# Searching numbers in file separated by many blank spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, input, spyder

I need to build a python code to store the python numbers that are in a file. The lines where those numbers are starts with a word "Mark" and then I have blank spaces and three columns of numbers, like this:

```
Mark    1     2    3 
Mark    4     4    6
```

Where the number of blank spaces between the numbers are not known. I know how to read the file line by line searching for the word line:

```
with open("doc.dat") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("Mark"):
```

But I do not know how to call the condition for extracting the numbers and passing them to a variable. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a string method "split". Then you can use "int" to convert a string to a number.

Comment: The point is that I do not know how many blank spaces I have between each number, so I guess I can not use "" as delimiter for split, can I?

Comment: @PaulRoberts `nums = list(map(int, line.split()[1:]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can extract numbers with this code :

```
with open("doc.dat") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("Mark"):
            line = line.strip()[4:].strip()
            numbers_list = []
            for letter in line:
                if letter != ' ':
                    numbers_list.append(int(letter))
            print(numbers_list) #its list of numbers
```